# Obtaining the date of 2 Saturdays ago and Last Friday

Tags: sql-server, date

How can I obtain the date of 2 Fridays ago and 2 Saturdays ago (SQL Server 2012+)

For example,

- if run today, Monday Oct 12, my query should result in Sat Oct 3 and Friday Oct 9
- if run on Tuesday Oct 20, my dates should be Sat Sat Oct 10 and Friday Oct 16

I am looking for an answer like `select xyz getdate() ...`.

Comment: Oct 9 and Oct 16 are just one Friday before Oct 12 and Oct 20, respectively. I gave you an answer based on "1 Friday ago" :-)

Comment: True, I amended. Thanks for your answer

Answer (score 1):

@Andresbi, your examples states 2 Saturdays before and **1 Friday before**.

I think this code gives you the result:

```
declare @dt datetime = '20201020'

select
    (
        /* Previous sunday */
        @dt - datepart(dw, @dt) + 1
        /* Previous saturday */
        - 1
        /* and the saturday before */
        - 7
    ),
    (
        /* Previous sunday */
        @dt - datepart(dw, @dt) + 1
        /* Previous friday */
        - 2
    )
```

Comment: Exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
select dateadd(day, -08, dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()), 0))
select dateadd(day, -10, dateadd(wk, datediff(wk, 0, getdate()), 0))
```